# How can I loop through two tasks in a role using with_sequence?

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

Problem

- I need to loop through two separate tasks with_sequence as the `{{ item }}` value is the name of my stack.
- For each integer in `with_sequence`, it needs to loop `{{ item }}` through task1 once, then loop through task2 once. Once it goes to the next integer, lets say from 0 to 1, it needs to repeat the loop of going through `task1` once then `task2` until it reaches 10.

This is my failed attempt at trying to get it to work but just adding it here as an example of what I'm trying to do. Is there a better way on how to do this with a loop?

```
# /roles/app1/tasks/main.yml

---
- name: Include env vars to pass to tasks
  include_vars:
    file: "./roles/app1/vars/{{ cluster }}_vars.yml"



# tasks file for infra

- name: Run through each task in serial using with_sequence
  include_tasks:
    - ./roles/app1/tasks/task1.yml
    - ./roles/app1/tasks/task2.yml
  with_sequence: "start=0 end=10"
```

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestions on how to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: and include_tasks has no list as parameters, only one file..so you have to review totally your code.. no solution with what you are showing